# POVM three-qubit circuit for symmetric quantum states

Tags: quantum-state, circuit-construction, mathematics, quantum-operation, povm

I have been reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0308098) but don't yet understand how to implement a circuit to determine in which state the qubit is *not* for a cyclic POVM. More specifically, I want to implement a cyclic POVM with $m=3$;

**Update**: I came across having to implement this unitary matrix:
$$ 
   M=
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1 \\
   1 & w \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$
Where $w$ is a third root of unity using rotations, after which I am stuck.

Comment: That's not a unitary matrix unless w=-1..

Answer (score 5):

This is not the unitary that you have to implement: you need a two-qubit unitary
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & \omega & \omega^2 & 0 \\
1 & \omega^2 & \omega & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{3}
\end{array}\right),
$$
where $\omega=e^{2i\pi/3}$, the point being that if you introduce an ancilla qubit in the state 0, apply this unitary, and then measure in the computational basis, the 3 measurement outcomes 00, 01 and 10 correspond to the 3 POVM elements.

I don't (yet) have a circuit implementation for this. You'll see the paper you cite carefully avoids talking about the Fourier transform in non-power of 2 dimensions. You certainly could use the standard constructions based on Givens rotations, but the result is going to be fairly horrible.

Here's an attempt at a circuit. I've made a few tweaks since I last ran it through a computer to check, so it's always possible that a slight error has crept in, but broadly...
[image]
Here, I'm using $Z^r$ to denote
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\pi r} \end{array}\right),
$$
and
$$
V=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \sqrt{2} \\ -\sqrt{2} & 1
\end{array}\right).
$$

Comment: Hmm, I was actually talking about F2, not the whole unitary. Or, I am missing something?

Comment: @chubakueno You said you wanted $m=3$, which means you need $F_3$, which is a $3\times 3$ matrix which we must embed into a $4\times 4$ matrix if we're using qubits.

Comment: I understand now. So, is there an example of IQFT for non power of twos there? I would be surprised to find there isn't, but what do I know.

Comment: @chubakueno I didn't immediately find one. I've now constructed one for the $m=3$ case, but don't have time right now to write it into a circuit.

Comment: If you were kind enough to write the circuit as a multiplication of matrices, or even paint, I will gladly accept your answer :)

Comment: @xbk365 once i’m done with the evening’s childcare responsibilities...

Answer (score 2):

Check this
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & \omega & \omega^2 \\
1 & \omega^2 & \omega \\
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
H & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\sqrt{2} & 0 & 1 \\
0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -\sqrt{2} \\
\end{array}\right) \cdot 
M_{3}
$$

$$M_{3} = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i\omega^2 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i\omega \\
0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\omega^2 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\omega \\
\end{array}\right)
$$

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
i\omega^2 & i\omega \\
-\omega^2 & -\omega \\
\end{array}\right) = X \cdot S \cdot X \cdot Z \cdot H \cdot \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\omega^2 & 0 \\
0 & \omega \\
\end{array}\right) \cdot Z
$$